Java Instancio generates same values on large models
I have an object
public class TestObject  {
    String someValue;

    //getters and setters
}

If i generate it many times independently, i will get some of values not unique:
Set<String> sets = new Hashset();
for (int i=0; i < 5000; i++){
    sets.add( Instancio.create(TestObject.class).getSomeValue() );
}
assertThat(sets).hasSize(5000); //fail sometimes

I have no seed configuration over my test classes. Is there a way to ensure all values of Instancio are unique?
I know, i can generate list of objects and set there .withUnique(...) via Instancio, but i cannot do this way in my case

What's your end goal? In the example, you are generating a Set of strings. If you can't use withUnique() you could also generate a stream of distinct values Instancio.stream(String.class).distinct().limit(5000). It's hard to answer the question with the provided information though.
